# find where all tags and none of tags

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection with stories that each have tags:

```
var StorySchema = new Schema({
        id          : {
            type       : Number,
            unique     : true,
        },
        name        : String,
        tags        : [{
            id          : Number,
            name        : String,
            url         : String,
        }],
});
```

I'm trying to select all stories that have all of tags `[{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}]` and none of tags `{id:4},{id:5}`

The closest I got is:

```
{
  tags : {
    $all:[{
      $elemMatch : {
        id: 1
      }
    }, {
      $elemMatch : {
        id: 2
      }
    }, {
      $elemMatch : {
        id: 3
      }
    }],
    $nin : [{
        id : 4
      }, {
        id : 5
    }]
  }
}
```

But it seems like the `$nin` part isn't doing it's job.

Also, I'm not very clear on why I need to use `$elemMatch` in the `$all` part of the selector. If I leave it out I get no results. Any clearification would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution:

```
{
  tags : {

    $all : [
      {
        $elemMatch : {
          id: 1
        }
      },
      {
        $elemMatch : {
          id: 2
        }
      },
      {
        $elemMatch : {
          id: 3
        }
      }
    ],

    $not : {
      $elemMatch : {
        id: { $in : [4,5] }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or, written a a js function building the selector (using `underscore.map()`):

```
var selector = {

  tags : {

    $all : _.map(includeTagIds, function(includeTagId){
      return {
        $elemMatch : {
          id : includeTagId
        }
      };
    }),

    $not : {
      $elemMatch : {
        id: { $in : excludeTagIds }
      }
    }
  }
};
```